# Unable to locate an element using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

Sorry if my question format is wrong as i am new to programming and StackOverFlow. I am unable to locate the download button using class or any other method. currently trying to resolve using xpath but i have heard xpath is not reliable method. I am trying to scrape wikiloc site to download all track paths within a specific location. The problem might of login as i might not be logged in when scraping. BTW I use google colab mostly. My code is below:

```
driver.get('https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/start.do')
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('testacount852')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('49Vchu4njDrrT7.')
driver.find_element_by_id('submit-button').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.get("https://www.wikiloc.com/trails/outdoor/france/brittany")
links = []
temp_links = []
names = []
temp_names = []
for _ in range(4):
  temp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.trail-title.dont-break-out')
  temp_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in temp]
  temp_names = [x.text for x in temp]
  links = links+temp_links
  names = names+temp_names
  try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
    time.sleep(2)
  except:
    break
for link in links:
  driver.get(link)
  driver.find_element_by_id('download-button').click()
  time.sleep(4)
  driver.find_element_by_class_name('active').click()
  time.sleep(4)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input").click()
  time.sleep(4)

df['Names'] = pd.Series(names)
df['Links'] = pd.Series(links)
df.to_csv('test1.csv')
driver.close()
```

Here is the link to my credentials
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ6bZ.png

Comment: Which element isn't working, that big long xpath? We will need the full HTML of the page under test in order to find a good selector.  I tried to follow your test steps to get to the page but I couldn't log in.

Comment: Yes!! the long xpath . thats what i thought maybe login is not working so the download button does not appear . is there a way so my login works correctly

Comment: Well, you need a valid username and password, which those do not appear to be. I don't think anyone here can help you with that.

Comment: The credentials are correct. i have checked them myself but the headless browser does not seem to login properly . I tried without headless and it seems it puts the credentials then opens the specified link. As a test , I stopped my script there and checked whether I am logged in or not and I saw I was not logged in by the browser. The same method I  had used with facebook (of course with other credentials) but there was no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice tutorial on youtube (the guy teaches using this very funny cookie clicker game); it features the try/except I have below which is my goto for accessing selenium items. I was able to get it working with the code shown below, hope this helps...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/start.do')
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('testacount852')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('49Vchu4njDrrT7.')
driver.find_element_by_id('submit-button').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.get("https://www.wikiloc.com/trails/outdoor/france/brittany")
links = []
temp_links = []
names = []
temp_names = []
for _ in range(4):
  temp = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.trail-title.dont-break-out')
  temp_links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in temp]
  temp_names = [x.text for x in temp]
  links = links+temp_links
  names = names+temp_names
  try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
    time.sleep(2)
  except:
    break
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    try:
        downloadbutton = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#download-button")))
        downloadbutton.click()
    except:
        print("Couldn't find the download button")
        pass
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('active').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input").click()
    time.sleep(4)

df['Names'] = pd.Series(names)
df['Links'] = pd.Series(links)
df.to_csv('test1.csv')
driver.close()
```

Comment: i am talking about the long xpath. it does not appear to be found by selenium

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Comment: I see....unfortunately I (pressume) am not able to get that far as I am met with a) google captcha and b) invalid user/pass credentials.

Answer (score 0):

2 question:

1. After clicking the download button, there is not webelement with class name 'active'?
2. What are you trying to find by this xpath and in which page '/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input'?
   ========================================

***Update:***

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//li/a[text() ='File']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='btn-download-file']").click()
```

Comment: 1. The first download button by id ('download-button') is detected which redirects us to another page where it asks us to choose method of download. second button ('active') is also detected which opens the a menu where the real download button (the xpath) should be but is not detected

Comment: second button becomes active class only after you click on it. So its not the right way of trying to find the element. Updated my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will keep this in mind after bypassing the captcha.

Comment: Not click, but click()

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem. It was captcha that was breaking it . I was unable to login and the download button (xpath) will not be available until I login . Thanks guys for helping me out specially @ShawnRamirez for pointing the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the login problem using cookies instead of providing credentials:

So instead of providing

```
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('testacount852')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('49Vchu4njDrrT7.')
driver.find_element_by_id('submit-button').click()
```

I bypass login with:

```
driver.get('https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/start.do')
driver.add_cookie({"name": "SESSION", "value": "##############"})

driver.add_cookie({"name": "wluseruuid", "value": "****************"})
driver.add_cookie({"name": "_wlutm", "value": "********************"})
driver.add_cookie({"name": "wikiloc_cookie_consent", "value": "**********"})
driver.add_cookie({"name": "JforumSSO", "value": "************"})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).